# Wordpress Vimeo integration

Tags: php, wordpress, vimeo

I want to check if a user has uploaded a video so that i can send it to vimeo then delete the local file after updating the url in the database

```
function check_attachment(){
         $video_mimes = array(
                        'video/mpeg',
                        'video/mp4', 
                        'video/quicktime'
                              );
      foreach ($video_mimes as $video_mime) {
             if($video_mime == get_post_mime_type( $attachment->ID )){
                     $upload_url =  get_attached_file( $attachment->ID);
                     $response = upload_to_vimeo($upload_url);//e.g videos/987654
                     update_attached_file( $attachment->ID, $response );
                     unlink($upload_url);//delete local file
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('success');  </script>";
       }
 }
  add_action('save_post', 'check_attachment');
```

my issue is `get_post_mime_type` is returning `false` and whenever i refresh the page the script executes even when its not a 'new post'. Maybe the `save_post` hook causes this, not sure